# Need help in creating Scheduling Control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need to create a scheduling control in ASP.NET. Meeting slots are fixed to 30 minutes.
I am showing the slots in tabular format.

My main concern is to DateTime and slot timing like **4 to 4 4:30**  to be read in code when user clicks particular cell in table, using HtmlTable control.

Table is created dynamically. Unfortunately the TableCell control don't have a click event.

In short, how can I detect the DateTime and timing from cell in the table by?

Comment: No question and you have not outlined your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheive what you are suggesting you could add a button control to each cell as you are dynamically creating them. You will need to add the event to the button as you are adding them. As you want the slot time I would suggest using the command click event and assigning the specific slot time to the command argument property of the button control.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying for a component, I'd save yourself lots of bother and just use [DayPilot Pro](http://www.daypilot.org/). Or if you want open source, [DayPilot Lite](http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but a great control is Telerik's RadScheduler: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx